# Show $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ is independent if and only if $P(A_{i_{1}} \cdots A_{i_{k}})=\prod_{j=1}^{k} P (A_{i_{j}})$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

This is the second part of exercise question from book *Probability for statistician*.

b) Show that $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ are independent if and only if
$$
P\left(A_{i_{1}} \cdots A_{i_{k}}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{k} P\left(A_{i_{j}}\right)
$$
whenever $1 \leq i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k} \leq n$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$.

In part a) we are asked to prove:

Show that $P(A B)=P(A) P(B)$ if and only if $\left\{\emptyset, A, A^{c}, \Omega\right\}$ and $\left\{\emptyset, B, B^{c}, \Omega\right\}$ are independent $\sigma$ -fields.

---

Before the exercise, the book states the definition of independent $\sigma$-field and independent event as follow:

1. Consider various sub $\sigma$ -fields of $\mathcal{A}$. Call such $\sigma$ -fields $\mathcal{A}_{1}, \cdots, \mathcal{A}_{n}$ independent $\sigma$ -fields if they satisfy
   $$
   P\left(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n}\right)=\prod_{1}^{n} P\left(A_{i}\right)
   $$
   whenever $A_{i} \in \mathcal{A}_{i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.
2. Events $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ are independent events if $\sigma\left[A_{1}\right], \cdots$, $\sigma\left[A_{n}\right]$ are independent $\sigma$ -fields; here we let
   $$
   \sigma\left[A_{i}\right] \equiv\left\{\emptyset, A_{i}, A_{i}^{c}, \Omega\right\}
   $$

---

**My idea** is that $P\left(A_{i_{1}} \cdots A_{i_{k}}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{k} P\left(A_{i_{j}}\right)$ implies the $\sigma$-field generated by ay $A_{i_{1}} \cdots A_{i_{k}}$ are independent from a) part of the question, hence $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ are independent but I am not sure how to write the proof rigorously. i.e.

$P\left(A_{i_{1}} \cdots A_{i_{k}}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{k} P\left(A_{i_{j}}\right)$
whenever $1 \leq i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k} \leq n$ with $1 \leq k \leq n $ implies $\sigma[A_{i_j}]$ are independent for any $1\leq i_j\leq n$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma[A_i]$ are independent for each $n\geq 2$. It seems the $\Rightarrow$ has lots of gaps within it.

**Could someone please address this question for me or at least gives me some clues to solve the problem?** Also, the first part only involves two events while in second part there are $n$ events. Usually statement that satifies in $n=2$ case can be extended to $n=N$ where $N$ is a finite number but I don't know how the extension can be proved.

Comment: I would try an inductive argument, where you try to apply part a) with $A = A_1, B = A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_n$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use the definitions from your book and let us solve:

> b) Show that $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ are independent if and only if
> $$
> P\left(A_{i_{1}} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{k}}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{k} P\left(A_{i_{j}}\right)
> $$
> whenever $1 \leq i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k} \leq n$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$.

(We will explicitly note the intersections $\cap$, so, for instance, $P(AB)$ will be written $P(A \cap B)$).

**Solution of b**: $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ are independent. Then by definition  $\sigma[A_{1}], \cdots, \sigma[A_{n}]$ are independent $\sigma$-fields. So,
$$
P\left(E_{1} \cap \cdots \cap E_{n}\right)=\prod_{1}^{n} P\left(E_{i}\right)
$$
whenever $E_{i} \in \sigma[A_{i}]$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Given any set of indexes $I =\{i_1, \cdots , i_k\}$ such that $1 \leq i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k} \leq n$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$, define $E_i = A_i$ if $i\in I$  and $E_i = \Omega$ if $i \notin I$. Then $E_{1} \cap \cdots \cap E_{n} = A_{i_{1}} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{k}}$ and $P(E_i) = 1$ if $i \notin I$, so we have

$$
P\left(A_{i_{1}} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{k}}\right)=P\left(E_{1} \cap \cdots \cap E_{n}\right)=\prod_{1}^{n} P\left(E_{i}\right)= \prod_{j=1}^{k} P\left(A_{i_{j}}\right)
$$

$(\Leftarrow)$
Suppose $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ are not independent. Then   $\sigma[A_{1}], \cdots, \sigma[A_{n}]$ are not independent $\sigma$-fields.

So, there are $E_{i} \in \sigma[A_{i}]$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, such that
$$
P\left(E_{1} \cap \cdots \cap E_{n}\right)\neq\prod_{1}^{n} P\left(E_{i}\right)
$$

Then, clearly $E_{i} \neq \emptyset $ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

So, for each $i \in   \{1, \cdots n\}$, $E_i$ has only three possibilities: $E_i=A_i$ , $E_i=A_i^c$ and $E_i=\Omega$.

Let $I= \{i : 1 \leq i \leq n \textrm{ and } E_i= A_i\} $, $J= \{i : 1 \leq i \leq n \textrm{ and } E_i= A_i^c\}$ and $K = \{i : 1 \leq i \leq n \textrm{ and } E_i= \Omega\}$.
\begin{align*}
P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup J} E_{i}  \right) &=
P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup J \cup K} E_{i} \right) = 
P\left(E_{1} \cap \cdots \cap E_{n}\right)\neq \\
& \neq \prod_{1}^{n} P\left(E_{i}\right) = 
 \prod_{i \in I \cup J \cup K} P\left(E_{i}\right)=
 \prod_{i \in I \cup J} P\left(E_{i}\right)
\end{align*}

So,
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup J} E_{i}  \right) \neq  \prod_{i \in I \cup J} P\left(E_{i}\right)$$

Now, suppose $j\in J$, then $E_j= A_j^c$, so we have

\begin{align*}
P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\})} E_{i}  \right) &- P\left(\left (\bigcap_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\})} E_{i} \right ) \cap A_j \right) = 
P\left(\left (\bigcap_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\})} E_{i} \right ) \cap A_j^c \right) = \\
& = P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup J} E_{i}  \right) \neq \\ 
& \neq  \prod_{i \in I \cup J} P\left(E_{i}\right)
= \left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\} )} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right ) (1 -P(A_j)) == \\
& = \left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\} )} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right )  - \left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\} )} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right )P(A_j) 
\end{align*}

So we have that
$$ P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\})} E_{i}  \right) \neq \prod_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\} )} P\left(E_{i}\right)
$$
or
$$ P\left(\left (\bigcap_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\})} E_{i} \right ) \cap A_j \right) \neq \left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup (J\setminus \{j\} )} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right )P(A_j) 
$$
So, in both cases we can remove $j$ from $J$ (in the first case, $j$ will be simply removed from $J$ and in second case $j$ will be removed from $J$ and added to $I$).

Since $J$ is finite, we will get  a set of index $I'$ such that

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I'} E_{i}  \right) \neq  \prod_{i \in I'} P\left(E_{i}\right)$$

and, for all $i \in I'$, $E_i=A_i$. So there are $1 \leq i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k} \leq n$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$ such that
$$
P\left(A_{i_{1}} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{k}}\right)\neq \prod_{j=1}^{k} P\left(A_{i_{j}}\right)
$$

**Remark**: Here is another way to prove the $(\Leftarrow)$ part of b).

Suppose, for all $1 \leq i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k} \leq n$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$,
$$
P\left(A_{i_{1}} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{k}}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{k} P\left(A_{i_{j}}\right) \tag{1}
$$
We want to prove that $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{n}$ are independent. It means,  by definition,  $\sigma[A_{1}], \cdots, \sigma[A_{n}]$ are independent $\sigma$-fields, which means, for all $E_{i} \in \sigma[A_{i}]$ where $1 \leq i \leq n$,
$$
P\left(E_{1} \cap \cdots \cap E_{n}\right)=\prod_{1}^{n} P\left(E_{i}\right) \tag{2}
$$
So, given any $\{E_{i} \}_{i\in \{1, \cdots n\}}$ such that $E_{i} \in \sigma[A_{i}]$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, if there is $i \in   \{1, \cdots n\}$ such that $E_i=\emptyset$,  then $(2)$ is trivially true and we are done. So, suppose that, for all  $i \in   \{1, \cdots n\}$,  $E_i\neq\emptyset$.

So, for each $i \in   \{1, \cdots n\}$, $E_i$ has only three possibilities: $E_i=A_i$ , $E_i=A_i^c$ and $E_i=\Omega$.

Let $I= \{i : 1 \leq i \leq n \textrm{ and } E_i= A_i\} $, $J= \{i : 1 \leq i \leq n \textrm{ and } E_i= A_i^c\}$ and $K = \{i : 1 \leq i \leq n \textrm{ and } E_i= \Omega\}$. From $(1)$,

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I } E_{i}  \right) = \prod_{i \in I } P\left(E_{i}\right)$$

And then it easy to see that

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup K} E_{i}  \right) =  \prod_{i \in I \cup K} P\left(E_{i}\right)$$

Now, take one $j\in J$, then $E_j= A_j^c$. Note that, from $(1)$, we also have
$$
P\left(\left (\bigcap_{i \in I \cup K} E_{i} \right ) \cap A_j \right) =
\left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup K} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right )P(A_j)
$$

So, we have
\begin{align*}
P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I  \cup K \cup \{j\}} E_{i}  \right) & = P\left(\left (\bigcap_{i \in I \cup K} E_{i} \right ) \cap A_j^c \right) = \\
&=P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I \cup K} E_{i}  \right) - P\left(\left (\bigcap_{i \in I \cup K} E_{i} \right ) \cap A_j \right) = \\
& = \left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup K} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right )  - \left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup K} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right )P(A_j) =\\
& = \left ( \prod_{i \in I \cup K} P\left(E_{i}\right)\right ) (1 -P(A_j)) =  \prod_{i \in I  \cup K \cup \{j\}} P\left(E_{i}\right)
\end{align*}

Since $J$ is finite, we have by finite induction,
$$
P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I  \cup K \cup J } E_{i}  \right) =
\prod_{i \in I  \cup K \cup J } P\left(E_{i}\right) \tag{3}
$$
but $(3)$ is exactly the same as $(2)$, that we  had to prove. $\square$

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed comment! It's extremely clear and well-written! sorry I was busy with other homework these past two days and didn't make the answer on time